# How do I replace SherlockListFragmentActivity using appcompat-v7?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm replacing `SherlockFragmentActivity` library with `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`

But how do I go about `SherlockListFragmentActivity`? There's no `ActionBarListActivity`...

Answer (score 0):

So I did

```
public class ActionBarListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actionbarlist);
        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }

    protected void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```